# UX feature: Option to make code part of the question as sticky or fixed (preferably at bottom-right of viewport)

Tags: feature-request, answers, code-block

I would really love a feature where the user has the option to detach code part of the question or (perhaps every code block) and make it a sticky or affixed, preferably to bottom-right of viewport.

This (in my opinion) really helps while trying to understand the answers in context of the code when the user scrolls down and question gets out of view in the viewport.

Users would not need to scroll back and forth to see the code in question. This will be particularly useful while trying to understand lengthy answers or multiple answers.

This thought occurred to me while trying to understand the git diff command output in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529441/how-to-read-the-output-from-git-diff).

The answer is quite long, and while trying to understand the code in the answer, I needed to scroll back & forth to see the code block in the answer. I thought if the code block could be affixed then it would be easier & I'd be able to consume the reply much faster.

So, why not have a affixed code block? What does everyone think?